# How to query many different shapes of document?

Tags: lucene.net

I have a scenario with Lucene where I'm not sure (after reading the documentation) what the best pattern for my code.

Essentially I have many (over 40) different "shapes" to my data. So for example, a news story with fields "Title", "Description" and "body text" and a technical kb-type article with fields like "overview", "problem", "solution", "workaround".

I know I can physically index these different non-uniform questions, but I don't much like the idea (with the sheer number of types of items I'll be searching) that my queries will end up like title:search OR description:search OR body:search OR overview:search OR ...... You get the idea...

Short of created a "standard" set of fields that get data shoehorned in to, what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

You could have 1 field to contain all text from every field, then also have the text broken down by each individual field. I've seen this work well in medical informatics.